# scheduled php file not executing at given interval, ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii, cron

My site has several background jobs written as yii console applications(aka: command). I have scheduled the command using the following syntax.

**Case 1:**

`php /var/www/test/console.php NewsLetter 10 | sed -e "s/^/$(date -R) /" >> /home/user4/logs/newsletter_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d).log`

If i run it from the ubuntu terminal, it creates the log file like `newsletter_2014-02-06.log` and inserts the timestamp at the begging of each line in the log file.

when it runs from the crontab, it doesn't process the command and i couldnt see anything at `/home/user4/logs/` location.

**Case 2:**

If i configure the job without shell command like the following,

`php /var/www/test/console.php NewsLetter 10>> /home/user4/logs/newsletter.log`

It works well and i could see the logs at `newsletter.log` file for each run from the crontab.

**Expected**: I want the output from cron job to be stored in a file with date append(log_2014-02-06.log). Each line in the log to have timestamp inserted.

Comment: Could you please this crontab entry `php /var/www/test/console.php NewsLetter 10 | sed -e "s/^/$(date -R) /" > /home/user4/logs/newsletter_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d).log 2>&1`

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL no luck

Answer (score 0):

Did you create `CConsoleCommand` classes for these actions? Then it's better to use the `yiic` command. It is also possible that the PHP command is not in your cronjob path. In that case you have to enter the full path to the PHP command. My cronjobs looks something like this (DirectAdmin system):

```
/usr/local/bin/php /path/to/yii/folder/protected/yiic actionToRun
```

For more information on creating `CConsoleCommand` classes you can check [this acticle on YiiFramework.com](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console#console-command-action).